# Android system certificate

Tags: java, android, permissions, system, x509certificate

I hope you can help me!

I have a Samsung i-9000 and i'm writing an application to enter the pin code of the SIM card if it has not already been done before.

I inserted android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in AndroidManifest.xml and the code in my Activty class is:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);            
clazz = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m.setAccessible(true);
it = (ITelephony)m.invoke(tm);
```

Now I know I have to sign my app with system certificate (or system key) to work with Android 2.3.3, but I don't how I can do it. I never signed an app before, especially as system app.

On google I found this for a Dream telephone:

*- In the AndroidManifest.xml of your application: under the  
element add the attribute android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system".*

*- Export an unsigned version of your Android application using 
Eclipse: right-click on the project >> Android Tools >> Export 
Unsigned Application Package.*

*- Use root-of-android-source-tree/out/host/your-host/framework/ 
signapk.jar to sign your app using platform.x509.pem and platform.pk8 
in root-of-android-source-tree/build/target/product/security*

I don't understand the meaning of the last point!!!! What have I to do step by step?? Where is /out/host//framework/ 
signapk.jar file?? Where are platform.x509.pem and platform.pk8? It says "/build/target/product/security", but where is this path?
The setps above are for a Dream telephone, maybe there is something different in Samsung i9000?

I don't know if it could be useful, hower I have a rooted Samsung i-9000 with Darky 10.2 ROM, development tool: Eclipse, OS: Windows7 32bit

Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: I tried on a rooted samsung i9000 with cyanogenmod, signed my app with platform.x509.pem and platform.pk8, and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Other than by getting a job at Samsung, or perhaps by taking hostages at gunpoint, you cannot sign applications with Samsung's signing key.

You are welcome to create your own firmware, in which case you control your own signing key. Of course, in that case, you could put this code right into the modified firmware.