# Can i create MOTION_EVENT programmatically?

Tags: android, events

I am developing an application in which I have to implement this part . I have to implement motionevents (like action down , action up) without the touch from user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtain a new [`MotionEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#obtain%28long,%20long,%20int,%20int,%20android.view.MotionEvent.PointerProperties%5B%5D,%20android.view.MotionEvent.PointerCoords%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and use [`dispatchTouchEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29).

Comment: i didn't get your point , can you please provide me a link or sample code ?

Comment: one more thing i want to do this through service not from an activity

Comment: What is your requirement? Are you developing some sort of automated UI testing service?

Comment: I am developing Bluetooth HID driver for mouse . What i have done so far is establish a Bluetooth connection between Bluetooth mouse and android phone . For i have use intent service for establish connection . Now this service is broadcasting mouse key events and x,y values . IME service which i have created has broadcast receiver   , now from here i want to simulated the mouse movements through motion event . So when user press left click on mouse , on android screen it select the respective object , that is why i want to simulate action down etc events .

Comment: I'm afraid, that may not be possible due to security restrictions as per [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5240821/165674). Perhaps if your app is signed with the System certificate, I guess you MAY be able to accomplish it somehow.

Comment: you are saying that i need to have root permissions for this ?

Comment: i have no idea regarding system certificate .

Comment: @user1155908 Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342049/android-system-certificate).

Comment: @Ahmed can you guide me to achieve the same function as my app would be running in background but I want to perform clicks on another apps or launcher of the android.

Comment: @skygeek excellent work done by this guy http://www.pocketmagic.net/2013/01/programmatically-injecting-events-on-android-part-2/#.UeEvDztJOSo .

Comment: @Ahmed yeah it's good help there but still it is not working on my rooted htc phone.